# Displaying content type in translated languages

Tags: i18n-l10n

So i have a Content Type named "My content type" (a simple form) and it has 5 fields.Now the default language of the field names is in English.[i.e feild1 is 'Name'].
I have translated the field names using the translation interface into 20 different  languages.And when users fill out the form the field names are in their respective and/or preferred language.I have created a custom page template for "My content type",and print the `$content` of the form there,but it is English (in other words,the field names are displayed as they are written in the content type itself).

My question : How can i display the results of the filled form so that the field names are in a specific translated language ?

A little visual example :

(this is how the "My content type" results are displayed, atm) :

```
First Name : lorem 
Last name : ipsum
Age : 55
Hobbies : lorem ipsum
```

(and i want the display the field names in a specific translated language,i.e. German)

```
Vorname : lorem
Familienname : ipsum
Alter : 55
Hobbys : lorem ipsum
```

This would be a sinch to do if i could use views (but sadly i can't,client specific rule)

If anyone can help ,i'd greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: Can you show us the example of how you render the form in your custom page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wrote a custom template for your content type. I think the problem would be rendering fields without any specific language

For Example:

In your Template to print a field:

```
$field_language = field_language('node', $node, 'body');

<?php print($node->body[$field_language][0]['value']); ?>
```

Since drupal 7 uses **Entity translation** . You need to select language for specific fields instead of node.